# How to make spark save it's temp files on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am running spark jobs on the AWS EMR cluster submitting them from the client host machine.
Client machine is just an EC2 instance that submits jobs to the EMR with yarn in cluster mode.

The problem is - spark saves temp files each of 200Mb like:

`/tmp/spark-456184c9-d59f-48f4-9b0560b7d310655/__spark_conf__6943938018805427428.zip`

Tmp folder is getting filled with such files very fast and I start getting failed jobs with the error:

`No space left on device`

I tried to configure `spark.local.dir` in spark-defaults.conf to point to my s3 bucket, but it adds user directory prefix to the path like this: `/home/username/s3a://my-bucket/spark-tmp-folder`

Could you please suggest how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I uploaded the zip archive `__spark_conf__6943938018805427428.zip`
  with spark libs to the s3 bucket.
- Then I specified it in the    `spark-defaults.conf` in the property
  `spark.yarn.archive     s3a://mybucket/libs/spark_libs.zip` on my
  client host machine that    submits jobs.
- Now spark loads only configs to the local tmp folder    that takes
  only 170Kb instead of 200Mb.